# sublime text 3 mac- comment selected part

Tags: macos, comments, sublimetext3

How to comment the selected or the highlighted text in sublime text 3 on a macbook.

```
Cmd + /
```

will comment out the whole line and not the selected part - should I just create a key mapping for this or is there an existing mapping??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block comment a selection the command is ( option + command + / ):

> <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Example:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": /*"make"*/
}
```

↳ [Sublime Keyboard Shortcuts - OS X](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html)